# Jssor-Slider - Change Thumb Text for Different Languages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I am trying to change thumb Text with javascript. But I´m unable to select a Thumb-Div by giving it an ID and change the innerHTML.

**HTML**

```
   <img u=image src="../slideshow/img/03_SmartTurtle_Applications_Phone_Phonecall.jpg" />
       <div u="thumb" id="test"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
   var switchText = document.getElementById("test");
   switchText.innerHTML = "new Text";
```

Also tried:

```html
       <img u=image src="../slideshow/img/03_SmartTurtle_Applications_Phone_Phonecall.jpg" />
            <div u="thumb"><div id="test"></div></div>
```

Could somebody help us, how can I change this dynamically.
Thanks.

Comment: Your first way works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6wsqodnt/. Are you executing your JS code before the elements exist in the page?

Comment: Usually it does, but here not. I also tried to execute the command with a button after the Site was completely loaded and the "switchText" variable is empty. The Thumb Text is an element of the Jssor-Slider.